# iMacros firefox: how to force firefox browser to close when an error found

Tags: laravel, imacros

I have tried

```
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
$iim1->iimExit();
$iim1->iimClose();
```

but not getting the result that I wanted. I want to stop and close the browser when an error occurred, for iimExit() and iimClose() it does not close the browser at all.

Comment: try `TAB CLOSE` command

Comment: In addition you should apply [the JavaScript Scripting Interface](http://wiki.imacros.net/Firefox#Javascript_Scripting_Interface) and remove the `SET !ERRORIGNORE YES` line because you "_want to stop and close the browser when an error occurred_".